# Sublime text in Ubuntu-Unity. Open file in current workspace

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, text-editor, ubuntu-unity

I have four workspaces (call them "spaces" or "desktops" if you like) in Ubuntu, with Unity on. I have multiple Sublime Text 2 windows open in each of them. If I open a new file from Nautilus in desktop 1, the file may be opened in any of the other desktops, depending on which of the Sublime windows has been opened last. Is there any way to change this behaviour to a more natural one, i.e. open the file in the most recent window of the workspace I am actually in?

Comment: Are you trying to make changes to the Sublime Text code? If you are just trying to change the configuration settings without changing the code, then you should ask on SuperUser.com, ubuntu.stackexchange.com, or unix.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is only for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the application launcher of Sublime Text. It can be found in `/usr/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop`.

To do so just run `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop` & add -n to the `Exec=` line so it looks like -

`Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n %F`

Also to note- on some systems sublime will cause cursor run on when used from the context menu. If that's the case while the .desktop is open to edit scroll down to the `StartupNotify=true` line & make it `StartupNotify=false`. This will prevent cursor run on...

Note: This may not be the *exact* thing you want. But this enables sublime text to open files in a new window, within the currently active workspace.